# Issue with deployment of a Laravel/Vite App with FTP

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, vite

First of all, i just want to say that i'm a bit of a begginer when it comes to deployment of any kind of app on a Web cloud. Here's my issue:

I have a Laravel 9 / Vitejs 4 app that i'm trying to deploy on an OVH Web cloud using only FTP. I used `npm run build` to build my app, and sent it to my cloud using FileZilla. Once in the cloud, i  moved the `index.php` file from `www/public` to `www` and changed some line in it so it can refer to the correct files / folders.
But, and i don't understand why, CSS won't load and my login page appears as a pure HTML page. My css file (and js to) is in it's own folder in `www/public`.

Here's some files that could provide some clues:

app.blade.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['public/css/style.css', 'public/js/app.js'])
</head>
<body>
    [...]
</body>
```

vite.config.js :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'public/css/style.css',
                'public/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

index.php :

```
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
 
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/
 
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}
 
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/
 
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
 
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/
 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
 
$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);
 
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();
 
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you change `APP_URL` in your `.env` to match your domain name?

Comment: It is, but it wasn't when I used `npm run build`, should i rebuild it?

Comment: Doesn't hurt to try. When you check your page source in the browser what url does `@vite(...)` produce?

Comment: i have this: `https://smartwaterwell.ovh/build/assets/style-0cb6d924.css`.
Also, i didn't really saw it before but I do have this error in the console `Loading module from “https://smartwaterwell.ovh/build/assets/app-4712b390.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`